# Making same SharePoint site Read only over internet

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, alternate-access-mapping, read-only, internet-sites

I have a SharePoint server 2019. running with multiple Web app and site collection underneath.

Now there is an requirement to make only one site collection available over internet and that too in read only mode.

I was wondering to user AAM to publish it over internet but not finding any solution to make it read only.

Any luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to set your site collection in read-only mode.

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "SiteURL" -LockState "ReadOnly"
```

[image]
Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/09/sharepoint-2013-set-site-collection-read-only.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-lock-status

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But If I apply either of these solutions then the site will read only in intranet as well as internet. Whereas I need a solution in which the same site will remain editable in intranet and read only in internet.